# Codeigniter Email Issue : Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

When sending emails using codeigniter, the emails are received but the page results in an error.
https://privatebin.net/?d89c7965b55f5712#+Y3hf+PE36m8bROxB/k4llwmcvOykt2JF+m72HhTLGU=

This is the error displayed when trying to send any email from script.

The code used for sending email is

```
$config['protocol']     = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host']    = 'mail.domain.com';
$config['smtp_port']    = '587';
$config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
$config['smtp_user']    = 'mail@domain.com';
$config['smtp_pass']    = '******'; 
$config['charset']      = 'utf-8';
$config['newline']      = "\r\n";
$config['mailtype']     = 'html'; // or html
$config['validation']   = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or not  
$this->email->initialize($config);

//$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from('mail@domain.com', $system_name);
$this->email->to($email);
$this->email->subject('Title');
$this->email->message($message);
$send=$this->email->send();
```

This was the response from hosting provider:

> We have implemented anti-spoofing policies on our server to curb spoofing, hence you won't be able to use the mail function if the FROM/TO email address is not from the same domain.
>
> I suggest you the following solution to resolve the issue.
>
> 1. Change the FROM address as something@domain.com.
> 2. Use SMTP authentication to send emails. [Recommended solution]

Comment: and the question would be ?

Comment: how to correct the error???

Comment: your host provided the answer

Comment: what should I change in the code?

Comment: are you reading the same txt i am?

Comment: Its not enough to see an error message. **you have to read and inwardly digest it as well**

Comment: Make sure that `gandhibhavan@gandhibhavan.org` actually exists as a valid email address on this server, as that is the address you are sending from. Or change the code to use an already existing (valid) email address on the sender

Comment: Actually I don't get what they said.

Comment: The mails were working fine , now this error came up.

Comment: Spend a few extra dollars and get good hosting. That's the real answer. When hosts start limiting or restricting what you do, they've crossed a red line.